# jQuery Calls to .NET WebMethod Working Out of Order

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am using lot of .NET WebMethod calls in my web application using jQuery. My calls are not working in the expected order. The first time the page loads it works fine, and after reloading the page, the WebMethod calls are disordered. How do I make it always work one by one in the expected order?

I am using jQuery `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) { },
    error: function (msg) { alert(msg.error); }
});
```

Comment: Are you using $.Ajax?

Comment: yes..                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: ",
                        data: '',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                      
                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            alert(msg.error);
                        }
                    });

Comment: Could you please click the Edit link under your question and add this information to the question. That will help you get a response.

Comment: I clarified the grammar as well as I could and clarified the question. I also added the `$.ajax()` call example from your comment. If there are any other details you can add to help clarify the question, that would help. How do you make all of the calls? What triggers them to be made? Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 2):

Add `async: false` option in ajax. By default Ajax make async call hence order is not guaranteed.

```
$.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
       async : false, // Add this
       url: "", 
       data: '', 
       contentType: "application/json; 
       charset=utf-8", 
       dataType: "json", 
       success: function (response) { }, 
       error: function (msg) { alert(msg.error); } 
});
```